# Why does this regexp fail to match given text?

Tags: php, regex

I have the following regexp in php:

```
/title="([a-zA-Z0-9 ]*)" data-nav="followers/
```

and I also have a really long text that has this somewhere:

```
title="8 906 Seguidores" data-nav="followers"
```

But the regexp fails to match the text. If I modify the regexp to this:

```
/title="(.*)" data-nav="followers/
```

It matches.

I am using the `preg_match` php function.

Comment: You could use an `\s` for any whitespace, and `\p{L}` (with the `/u` flag) for any letter. However, you could also parse if with DOM and just query the title attribute, it's an easy XPath.

Comment: What are you trying to capture? The title? Both Regexps work for me.

Comment: just get the capture group 1 through `$m[1]`

Comment: @Buzu Did you want to match only `8 906 Seguidores` ?

Comment: I know how to get the capture group, thanks!. I also tried with \s, but no luck. Using XPath, or the DOM interface is an idea, but not as quick as the regexp considering the document is quite large, and I have to process many like it. The first getexp works as is on another script I have.

Comment: Regex should work. Are you sure it's not that one of the characters is actually from a foreign alphabet without appearing that way? Or maybe some accent you didn't include in your example?

Comment: Yes, @AvinashRaj that is what I am trying to match. I'm using the second regexp, since it does the job, but I got curious as to why the first one does not work, even though it works on another script. Pretty weird stuff.

Comment: no, first regex won't match the exact string.

Comment: @SørenUllidtz that is something I thought too, but I could not see any character that may cause the fail.

Comment: Why not @AvinashRaj? maybe you can solve the mystery.

Comment: @Buzu see http://regex101.com/r/nC3yX8/1

Comment: I tested your example using phpliveregex and it worked there. Can you reproduce the error in a small example simply providing that bit to the regex? (Typing the string in yourself to make sure you don't copy paste some hidden char)

Comment: @AvinashRaj, Thanks, but I'm not looking for a regexp to match the text, I just want to know why the one I provided doesn't match, but there is people here saying it does work for them, so I guess the issue is somewhere else.

Comment: see http://regex101.com/r/nC3yX8/2 . It works for me also.

Comment: @SørenUllidtz Strange thing is that the same regexp, works on another script with the same set of files. I actually copy-pasted it from the original script I wrote, which works. That is why it was so strange. The script runs through a list of twitter user names, and fetches their profile page to find the number of followers that they have. Not using the API is part of the fun...

Comment: I definitely don't know what is going on here... Thanks for all your help, my friends, and for confirming that it works for you. The problem must be somewhere else. I'll keep looking. Thanks!